# too many initializers for 'char []'

Tags: c++, строки, char

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main(){
    char a[] = {"qqq","www","eee"};
    cout << a[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Если написать string а не char то все работает, просто я немного не понял как это должно работать, пример взял из книги, там вот так было написано и я толком не понял там объявляется массив строк или массив символов, если массив строк то надо было написать вместо char string но почему написано char не пойму и поэтому до конца не ясно что хотел сказать автор, может это ошибка в книге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char a[] = {"qqq","www","eee"};
```

Здесь объявлен массив `char`'ов, т.е. массив отдельных символов. Если бы вы написали

```
char a[] = {'q','w','e'};
```

все было бы верно. Но у вас - массив строковых литералов, а это в C++ - `const char *`. Поэтому правильнее всего -

```
const char * a[] = {"qqq","www","eee"};
```

Когда вы пишете

```
string a[] = {"qqq","www","eee"};
```

то просто каждый строковый литерал преобразуется в объект типа `string`...

Кроме того, поскольку строка - это массив символов, можно объявлять и так:

```
char a[] = {"qqq"};
```

В этом случае вы объявляете один массив `char`'ов - три из которых `q`, а четвертый - нулевой символ. `a` при этом при использовании является адресом первого элемента (первой буквы `q`).